# How to set Windows backup filenames to incorporate my local timezone, rather than UTC?

Tags: windows-10, windows-backup

**Background:**

I've set my computer (Windows 10 Pro) to automatically back up a folder of my files every 10 minutes (and saved forever) to a network drive using *Settings > Update & Security > Backup*.

The resulting backed-up files are stored with the source filename plus a UTC date and time stamp appended, indicating the date and time of the backup.  For example, the file

***myfile.txt***

would be backed up as:

***myfile (2022_12_25 21_50_58 UTC).txt***

**Question:**

I live in the Pacific time zone (standard UTC-8:00, daylight UTC-7:00).  How do I make the backup date and time stamps in Pacific time instead of UTC?  Ideally, the date and time stamps would also automatically adjust for daylight savings time shifts.

I've looked through the Windows Backup options and advanced settings, and nothing is mentioned.